# Why should I implement rotateCounterClockwise() in ZXing?

Tags: zxing

I am creating a subclass to `LuminanceSource`. Is there a reason why I should expect to or have to implement `rotateCounterClockwise()`?

Implications to performance or reliability (or both)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always have `isRotateSupported()` and make that method throw an exception if you don't want to implement it.

It is provided because the interface does not know what your internal structure is like, so otherwise a rotation involves converting your data to a common format, performing the transform, then converting the common format data back into your format.

Comment: That's right. It exists because the framework can also try to scan at rotation, and that's why this method exists.